# In Django admin how to make manytomany'<select> element shows more options

Tags: python, django-admin

I use django admin to manage the movies and release companys,but when I edit the movie contents , I find the manytomany field  companys the select show only 4 companies, I want to make the select element show more elements ,How do I change the admin source code . 
My table is as below :

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('影片名称', max_length=100)
    nickname = models.CharField('别名', max_length = 100,blank=True)
    directors = models.CharField('导演们', max_length=200,blank=True)
    actors = models.CharField('演员们', max_length=200,blank=True)
    mins = models.CharField('片长', max_length=100,blank=True)
    pubdate = models.DateField('影片发布日期')
    age = models.CharField('影片年代',max_length=100,blank=True)
    score = models.CharField('评分', max_length=20,blank=True)
    plots = models.TextField('剧情',blank=True)
    poster_image_url = models.CharField('海报图片地址', max_length=500,blank =True)
    outid = models.CharField('外链id', max_length=32, unique=True)
    index = models.IntegerField('排序', max_length=5, default=0)
    createtime = models.DateTimeField('创建时间', auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField('状态', max_length=50, choices=MOVIE_STATUS_CHOICE, default='1')
    filmtype = models.CharField('影片类型', max_length=100,blank =True)
    certification = models.CharField('影片分级', max_length=200,blank =True)
    language = models.CharField('影片语言', max_length=100,blank =True)
    area = models.CharField('地区', max_length=50,blank =True)
    companys = models.ManyToManyField(Company,db_table='movies_companys', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'movie'
        verbose_name = "影片"
        verbose_name_plural = "影片"


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('发行公司名称',max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'company'
```

`

Comment: Can you include the code for you Company model please?

Comment: In addition it's better to set `u` before hieroglyphs not before `'movie'` because string `'movie'` has only ascii characters.

Comment: I just want to edit the ‘moive’ table，and want  ‘companys’ field to show more elements to select in select tag。my English is very poor，many thanks to the replys